# Help combining SharePoint formula statements - DATEIF and ISERROR

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am running a SharePoint formula that calculates the length of time (in yrs, months, and days) before a project expires.

In the "Will Expire" column the following formula is running:

```
=DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"Y")&" Years "&DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"YM")&" Months "&DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"MD")&" Days"
```

The "CurrentDate" column is updated daily as part of a Power Automate job. The "End Date" column is manually added as part of the project term.

For expired projects, a result is a negative number which is an error with DATEIF that shows up as #NUM!.

I do not want negative numbers to show and used DATEDIF to get an error in hopes of changing the error to something more user friendly.

However when adding an ISERROR statement - I cannot get the syntax of the combined statements to work.

Any help or ideas to use a better way appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid `#NUM!`, you should use `ISERROR` as below

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"Y")),"show error message",DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"Y"))
```

To match this with your formula, the final formula with `ISERROR` should like

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"Y")),"0",DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"Y"))," Years ",IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"YM")),"0",DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"YM"))," Months",IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"MD")),"0",DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"MD"))," Days")
```

**Output**

On error for all conditions, it should show

```
0 Years 0 Months 0 Days
```

> `ISERROR` returns `true` if there is an error. so that in the **If** clause. if there is an error, it will show your preferred statement. otherwise, it would calculate the DATEDIF.
> Read also **[Supported and Unsupported Columns in SharePoint Calculated Column Formula](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. SharePoint gives a "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported" error on the final formula. I will keep working on it.

Comment: I suggest to first try this line =IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"Y")),"show error message",DATEDIF(CurrentDate,[End Date],"Y")) and let me know if it raises any error

Comment: The problem seems to be with the text of "Years, Months and Days". Looks like I'm trying to do to much in this column. Think I will abandon trying things this way.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: I would suggest using CONCATENATE, I will update the answer, and please check and let me know

Comment: @DK524 I have updated the answer, please check it!

Comment: The updated syntax works. The text of Years, Months and Days is the issue. All the text gets added to the column even as the error code applies. The field shows the "error message, Year, error message, Months, error message, Days."  I'm thinking I'm trying to do to much in one field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117898/discussion-between-mohamed-el-qassas-mvp-and-dk524).